# How can I make Passport login session NOT persistent across Chrome windows and be cookie-based only?

Tags: node.js, session, express, cookies, passport.js

Currently I am using Passport with Express and have a local login strategy implemented, using `express-session`. The actual logic of the login works fine, but I noticed that once I log in from one tab, as soon as I open another Chrome window (even if it is in Incognito mode), it still shows me as logged in as that same user. I don't want this behavior, so that for testing purposes, I can emulate two different, simultaneously logged in users. Also, when I clear all my local cookies, I would like it to instantly treat me as logged off, but right now it is keeping me logged in (unless I explicitly point my browser to the /logout route which runs `req.logout();`. Here is the current setup (I left out irrelevant lines of code for brevity):

```
var passport = require('passport'),
    LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy,
    expressSession = require('express-session');

app.use(expressSession({ secret: 'keyboard cat', resave: false, saveUninitialized: false }));

passport.use('local-login-strategy', new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField: 'email',
    passwordField: 'password',
    passReqToCallback: true
}, function(req, email, password, done) { ... });

app.get('/login', function(req, res) { ... });

app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local-login-strategy', {
    successRedirect: '/dashboard',
    failureRedirect: '/login?loginFailedTryAgain'
});
```

Therefore, after digging around I tried using `cookie-session` instead by modifying the code as such:

```
var passport = require('passport'),
    LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy,
    cookieSession = require('cookie-session');

app.use(cookieSession({ secret: 'keyboard cat', key: 'someKey', cookie: {maxAge: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000} }));

passport.use('local-login-strategy', new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField: 'email',
    passwordField: 'password',
    passReqToCallback: true
}, function(req, email, password, done) { ... });

app.get('/login', function(req, res) { ... });

app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local-login-strategy', {
    successRedirect: '/dashboard',
    failureRedirect: '/login?loginFailedTryAgain',
    session: false
});
```

Unfortunately, that didn't work either.

Any ideas how to tweak this code to achieve my desired results?

Comment: Well your desired result is exactly how it should work. There is no way for your Node.js app to know who you are if you use incognito mode or delete cookies, so I'd suspect that there is something fundamentally wrong in your implementation if it really does do as you described.

Comment: I have a similar problem. When I open incognito windows it shows the session data.

Comment: If this problem is solved, please reply. I am stuck at the same problem.

Comment: For those who come across this post in the future and have this issue as I did: your app is not necessarily broken. Try using **2 browsers** to test. My app was syncing across incognito mode but using 2 browsers it worked as expected.